# How do I get a WPF context menu's original click point?

Tags: wpf, contextmenu

I've got a control with a context menu.  I don't manually pop it myself, I just set the `ContextMenu` property on the control

```
<PolyControl ContextMenu="{StaticResource PolyCtxMenu}"/>
```

One of the items on thecontext menu will issue a command that requires (as the `CommandParameter`) the mouse coordinate from where the mouse was when the user right-clicked to originally bring up the context menu.  But I don't see a way to get this.

```
<ContextMenu x:Key="PolyCtxMenu">
    <MenuItem Command="{Binding AddVertexCmd}"
        CommandParameter="... (Need the coordinate here)..." />
</ContextMenu>
```

I can control where the menu goes but I don't see an API to retrieve the original right-click position.

Is this possible without manually taking over the right-click handler popping up the menu myself?

Comment: You could handle the preview event, get the position and set a property in control or viewmodel.

Comment: Yeah it's looking like I'll have to do something like that.  I was hoping there was a property I could just refer to in XAML